# Value Type of 'FIRDatabaseReference' has no member 'observeSingleEvent'

Tags: firebase, error-handling, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have received the error of "Value Type of 'FIRDatabaseReference' has no member 'observeSingleEvent'" in my firebase app. I found this code on the firebase website but unfortunately it is not working in my app. I am writing the code to my app in *Swift 3* and am wondering if this could possibly be the problem.

Thanks
[image: ERROR IMAGE]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :-

```
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock : {(snapShot) in 

  print(snapShot)  

    })
```

What you are using is a syntax to **Swift3**